In eclipse console, duplicate logger messages are being printed
enter image enter image enter image   duplicate message are being printed in logger
For first test case, the message is printed once in the console. In the second test case, it is printed twice. In the third test case, it is printed three times, and so on for subsequent test cases.

Please don't post links to pictures of code or output, paste them here.

Seems that you manually set up logging and add log appenders during each test.

Just put your log initialise code in BaseClass as static { PropertyConfigurator... } 

To ensure one-time initialisation of logging for the JVM, you can set up the configuration in a static block:
class BaseClass{
    static {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    }
    ...

You can also assign log directly to a final field:
